# jquery toggle between classes from two different buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been having trouble with a button that I'm trying to get my head around.

Basically I have two buttons.
Button #1 is on the side bar and has two states with the following style

```
.Bt, .BtT {
height: 129px;
cursor: pointer;
background: url('../images/sideBtns.png') no-repeat;  
}

.BtT{
background-position: 0 -129px;
}
```

Then in my HTML `<div id="closeRefs" class="Bt">` (this is the one on the side)
And the second one which is

```
<a class="openRef" ...> ... </a>
```

Then my javaScript is as follows

```
    $("#closeRefs").click(function () {//SIDE BUTTON
        $(".Bt").toggleClass('BtT');
    });

    $(".openRef").click(function () {//REFERENCES OPEN
        $(".Bt").removeClass('Bt').addClass('BtT');
    });
```

This works up as follows:
Side button switches between the `background-position`, the reference button is able to also switch on the side button it is clicked (if the side button is not on). The problem persists when I click on the reference button, it switches on the side button and then when i click the side button it doesn't switch itself off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could because you are removing the class `Bt` when you click `openRef`. So when you click on `closeRefs` there is no element with class `Bt`

```
var $bt = $(".Bt");
$("#closeRefs").click(function () {//SIDE BUTTON
    $bt.toggleClass('BtT');
});

$(".openRef").click(function () {//REFERENCES OPEN
    $bt.removeClass('Bt').addClass('BtT');
});
```

Comment: effect click on openRef -> turns on side btn -> click on side btn -> side btn disappears.

Comment: the class for some reason is empty

Comment: actually the button seems to be hidden for some reason. It is invisible. It doesn't have the background css property for some reason

Comment: After I click on the refBtn the sideBtn turns on, then when i click on the side button to switch it off it disappears leaving just `class` (without anything in it)

Comment: Got it working! The toggle was wrong it is supposed to be $bt.toggleClass('Bt BtT');

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, this is what you're trying to do:
http://jsfiddle.net/KQ7EQ/

What Arun said is correct, you're removing `Bt` leaving the target div with nothing to go back to. Also, you're not setting a 'reset position'.

For example: 
When you remove `BlT` there's nothing telling the background to go back to its initial position.

If you add:

```
.Bt{
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

that will tell the background image to reset its position.

Also if you want `Bl` to be gone when `BlT`is active and vice-versa, you should use:

```
$bt.toggleClass('Bt').toggleClass('BlT');
```

Since `Bt` is there from the start, it will be removed on when you're adding `BlT` and the opposite when you call it again.